# How to work around RequestTimeTooSkewed in Fine Uploader

Tags: amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I'm using Fine Uploader with S3 and I have a client whose computer time is off, resulting in an S3 RequestTimeTooSkewed error.  Ideally, my client would have the right time, but I'd like to have my app be robust to this situation.

I've seen this post - https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/399 on how to automatically retry the request.  You take the ServerTime from the error response and use that as the time in the response.  An alternative approach would just be to get the time from a reliable external source every time, avoiding the need for a retry.  However, I'm not sure how to hook either approach into S3 Fine Uploader.  Does anyone have an idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution was provided in Fine Uploader 5.5 to address this very situation. From the [S3 feature documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/features/s3.html#accounting-for-browserclient-clock-drift):

If the clock on the machine running Fine Uploader is too far off of the current date, S3 may reject any requests sent from this machine. To overcome this situation, you can include a [clock drift value](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/options-s3.html#request.clockDrift), in milliseconds, when creating a new Fine Uploader instance. One way to set this value is to subtract the current time according to the browser from the current unix time according to your server. For example:

```js
var uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
    request: {
        clockDrift: SERVER_UNIX_TIME_IN_MS - Date.now()
    }
})
```

If this value is non-zero, Fine Uploader S3 will use it to pad the x-amz-date header and the policy expiration date sent to S3.